# Vuze won't let me delete anything, it says permission denied

Tags: 12.04, permissions, root, vuze

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04. In the Vuze downloads properties, it says `Owner: root`. I don't know how to change that. This has only happened in Ubuntu, not Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were probably running Vuze as root, so all files downloaded by it are now owned by root. Make sure Vuze is closed, open a terminal and go to the folder where the files in question are located. Then run the following command:

**`sudo chown -cR $USER:$(id -gn $USER) .`**

(Please note that the point at the end is part of the command). Now start Vuze and everything should work just fine.

Comment: On a side note, running file sharing software, internet browsers or other web based programs as root is a terrible idea and defeats the superior security model of Linux.